# Human sacrifice

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In "Retzei", human sacrifice is clearly mentioned:

> רְצֵה ה' אֱלהֵינוּ בְּעַמְּךָ יִשרָאֵל וּבִתְפִלָּתָם וְהָשֵׁב אֶת
> הָעֲבודָה לִדְבִיר בֵּיתֶךָ. וְאִשֵּׁי יִשרָאֵל וּתְפִלָּתָם.
> בְּאַהֲבָה תְקַבֵּל בְּרָצון.
>
> *Restore the service to Your Sanctuary, and accept the humans of Israel
> and their prayers with love and with favor.*

What were the details of these sacrifices? Who was chosen to be offered? How were they chosen? Could women be sacrificed too? What happened to their families? Etc.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: OK - This stretching it a little too far. The plural possessive of *Ish* is *Anshei*

Comment: @DanF No, when referred to as an non-human object, the plural of *Ish* is *Ishim*, e.g. as a type of angels. Possessive of *Ishim* would be *Ishei*. Human dead bodies – I presume shchita is required :-) – as sacrificial items would be *Ishim* too.

Comment: Ah - I see the connection. Thanks for pointing that out. Though, it makes my answer a little harder to formulate.

Comment: Not to take the fun out of this, but the Tur explains this verse that Michoel is Makriv the Neshamos of Tzadikim on a Mizbeach: ובמדרש יש מיכאל שר הגדול מקריב נשמתן של צדיקים על המזבח של מעלה ועל זה תקנו ואשי ישראל. So it's not really Purim Torah :-(

Comment: @user9022 +1 Amazing though. I genuinely thought I was intentionally mistranslating the text... I guess [my forced grammar](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55775/human-sacrifice?noredirect=1#comment147063_55775) is right too. [Not the first Purim question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55273/ptij-if-a-tree-falls-in-a-forest-and-no-one-is-around-to-hear-it-does-it-make) that happens to be a real one too.

Comment: The adulteress would explode in the Temple. That's probably the closest thing to a real human sacrifice.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117249/170

Answer (score 1):

This paragraph precedes the opening paragraph of *Birkat Kohanim* on Yom Tov. In the paragraph, starting *V'Te'arev* we ask G-d to accept our petitions as if they were an *olah and karban* - a burnt offering and a sacrifice.

What are the petitions about? Some people complain about the way the *Kohanim* sing when the *duchen*. They don't sing together and some of them can't sing at all. So these people are petitioning G-d that they don't have to suffer during *duchenin* listening to the lousy voices.

In truth, while these petitioners may be right, they have no right to petition at all, b/c *Birkat Koahnim* is a mitzvah and a beautiful *bracha* nonetheless.

So, because, in a sense, they are the ones who asked to be like a sacrifice, they are the ones selected to become that.

The service itself - during the sacrifice, they have to listen to the unvocal Kohanim that they protested against.