# What does sacrificing a soul mean?

Tags: korban, malach-angel, agada-stories-legends, tzaddikim, tractate-chagiga

The Talmud Bavli in [Chagiga 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b.6?lang=bi&with=Chidushei%20Agadot&lang2=en) mentions that there is a place where the angel Michael offers *korbanos* to Hashem. The *Chiddushei Aggados* commentary (can be seen on the above link on Sefaria) states a classic that I've seen in earlier sources as well -- that Michael sacrifices the souls of *tzaddikim*.

I wanted to know what that means exactly. It's clearly a symbolic image, so what does it mean to "offer the soul of the *tzaddik* as a *korban*?

Also, I understand the reason why Michael does it (as opposed to any other *malach*) is because he functions like a *kohen gadol* in the realm of the angels (which the *Chiddushei Aggados* also says). However, why is the help of a *malach* altogether needed -- wouldn't we consider the entire life of a *tzaddik* exactly that, -- a sacrifice of himself to Hashem, that is performed by the person himself?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Gemara says that Tzadikims death atone for the Averos of the Generation. So pashtus Michael is just the one to serve the "tzadik" as a korbon (once he's dead) on his way to meet HaShem... as a korbon has a shaychus to re'ach which the  Gemara says nose has a shaychus to soul Bec of rayach

Comment: See the meforshim on the brocho in the amida of retsai. v'ishai yisroel etc. who discuss this. since some but not all say it refers to this..

Comment: @interested thank you for the reference, could you possibly please point out specific commentators that may discuss my question?

Comment: @gt6989b Menachos 110 tosfos

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/7965/

Comment: @gt6989b All the meforshim on SA bring this tosfos.

Comment: @interested I looked at the Tosfos, but don't see how it is relevant. He does not answer either one of the questions I mentioned, just states it is a *machlokes* of *midrashim*.